# Do the later films in the "Night of the Living Dead" series use CGI?

Tags: effects, night-of-the-living-dead

series release history:

- Night of the Living Dead (1968)
- Dawn of the Dead (1978)
- Day of the Dead (1985)
- Land of the Dead (2005)
- Diary of the Dead (2007)
- Survival of the Dead (2009)

The 20-year gap between 1985 and 2005 naturally encompasses significant development in the field of computer-generated imagery — especially creating "apocalyptic landscapes" entirely on computers may have been tempting, budget-wise.

Comment: Requesting a new `night-of-the-living-dead-series` tag.

Comment: Noted, but not deemed necessary yet.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

All the later movies used a combination of standard cost-effective gags (fake blood, prosthetics, makeup, etc...) as well as CGI for the more involved shots.  You can usually find reference to them on the DVDs/Blu-Rays in the Special Features.  For example, you can see clearly that a reference to a CGI test reel exists on disc 2 of the Land Of The Dead release:

https://www.shoutfactory.com/product/land-of-the-dead-collector-s-edition?product_id=6375

Comment: I'm under the impression that Land of the Dead uses CGI for all blood splatter effects. I'm writing my answer at the time.

Comment: Here is [a source](https://web.archive.org/web/20080309173428/http://cinefantastiqueonline.com/2008/02/15/interview-george-romero-documents-the-dead-part-1/) for Diary of the Dead (2007). CGI-use in Survival of the Dead (2009) is mentioned in [the IGN review](https://www.ign.com/articles/2009/09/15/survival-of-the-dead-review).